# Как передать и обработать через html-форму значения полей с одинаковыми именами?

Tags: html, html-form

Практикуется ли такое вообще либо есть более изящное решение? Суть в следующем.
Есть определенный набор полей, в котором собираются сведения об объекте(например, комнате). Рядом ссылка "добавить комнату" . В форме появляется еще один набор таких же полей, с такими же именами. Как правильно записывать имена полей в такой форме и как их правильно обработать на сервере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос есть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25553419/6741620). Если коротко, то для имен полей нет требования к уникальности, просто в последующем, при разборе этих полей, вы можете обращаться к ним как к массиву.